# cscope shortcuts not showing all results of search

Tags: vim, cscope

I am using shortcuts of cscope in vim editor as per http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html

Shortcuts are not showing all results of the search but it is directly moving to one of the results.

At the end it goes to a specific result from the search and shows below result if I searched for my_func using shortcut:

(1 of 6): <<>>  * my_func:

Can anyone please let me know how to show all the results as the result of cscope shortcut in vim editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All results are available in the [Quickfix Window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix-window).

Type `:cope` to open the Quickfix Window.

There you will find all your results. Navigate over them with normal Vim movement. `<ENTER>` jumps to the result.

Comment: Thank you eckes. It helps. Usually all results are shown when we use cscope. I am not sure why it is not showing for me. Your solution helped.